# Read exported journal with colors and bold

Tags: systemd, journalctl

How inspect exported boot section from `journalctl -b -1 > bootlog.txt` in full color? Default exported format loses all colors and bold markup that is important to spot critical details.

It is possible to export to .json and some `export` format with `journalctl -b -1 -o export > bootlog.export`, but `journalctl` refuses to read it even if file is renamed to `bootlog.journal` and pointed to with `-D` option.

How people analyze exported `journalctl` data?

**UPDATE**: I was able to get colored output in file using a hack from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27397865/how-to-write-stdout-to-file-with-colors to trick `journalctl` that it is running in terminal:

```
script -q -c "journalctl -b -1 --no-pager" colored.txt > /dev/null
```

`less colored.txt` then shows those colors correctly. However, I have to kill terminal several times - debugging `script` command is a horrible experience.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `systemd-journal-remote`.

If you export a journal part to a file called `foodump` with:

```
journalctl --output=export --boot=-1 > foodump
```

`foodump` will be in the `Journal Export Format`.

You can then convert it back to a normal journal file with:

```
systemd-journal-remote --output=foodump.journal foodump
```

Or, in some distros (like Debian):

```
/lib/systemd/systemd-journal-remote --output=foodump.journal foodump
```

And view it with:

```
journalctl --file=foodump.journal
```

On Debian you can install `systemd-journal-remote` with `apt-get install systemd-journal-remote`. On Fedora `dnf install systemd-journal-remote`.

**TL;DR**

Debian:

```
journalctl --output=export --boot=-1 | \
  /lib/systemd/systemd-journal-remote --output=exported.journal -
```

Fedora:

```
journalctl --output=export --boot=-1 | \
  /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journal-remote --output=exported.journal -
```

View it:

```
journalctl --file=exported.journal
```

For further information consult [the manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-journal-remote.service.html).

Comment: Using `systemd-journal-remote` is a pain. Not only it should be installed and invoked as `/lib/systemd/systemd-journal-remote`, but the path is also different on Fedora `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journal-remote`.

Comment: Another problem is that `--output=foodump.journal` also creates another long file `foodump@....journal` that needs to be cleaned up.

Comment: seems to be outdated